# Odd behavior when trying to get the contents of a script element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I'm playing around with backbone and underscore templates.  When I try to dereference the contents of a script block (using `$("#people-templ").html()`) I get two different behaviors depending on the context of the call.  Inside the render function for the backbone view I get nothing returned.  If I get the contents of the script block outside any function, I get the valid HTML contents.  I tried this on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.  I stepped through with the debugger and validated that JQuery returned an empty array when calling `$("#people-templ")` within the callback function.  I was wondering if someone had an explanation for this behavior.

In index.html I have a simple template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="people-templ">
    <h1>People</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% people.each(function(person) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= person.get("firstName") %></td>
                    <td><%= person.get("lastName") %></td>
                </tr>
            <% }) %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
<script src='/javascripts/lib/jquery-2.0.3.js'></script>
<script src='/javascripts/lib/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='/javascripts/lib/backbone.js'></script>

<script src="/javascripts/main/index.js"></script>
```

Inside index.js I have the following Backbone view definition:

```
var peopleHtml = $("#people-templ").html();
var PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#foo",

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        var people = new People();
        var me = this;

        this.$el.empty();
        people.fetch({
            success: function(people) {
                var template = _.template(peopleHtml, { people: people });
                me.$el.html(template);
            },

           error: function() {
              console.error("Failed to load the collection");
           }
        });
     }
 });
```

This works.  The code gets the template from the script tag, Underscore processes it, and inserts the resulting markup into the DOM.  If I move `var peopleHtml = $("#people-templ").html();` inside of the callback, as such:

```
var PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: "#foo",

   initialize: function() {
       this.render();
   },

   render: function() {
       var people = new People();
       var me = this;

       this.$el.empty();
       people.fetch({
           success: function(people) {
              var template = _.template($("#people-templ").html(), { people: people });
              me.$el.html(template);
           },

           error: function() {
               console.error("Failed to load the collection");
           }
       });
    }
```

});

Then it seems that nothing is returned from `$("people-tempo").html()` and the code failed inside of underscore.js when it tries to do text replacement when processing the template.

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

**SOLVED thanks to Pointy**

```
<div id="foo"/>
```

and

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

are not the same thing.  If the former is used, everything from the div on down (including all my script elements) were replaced by the templates text.  using the latter, only the contents of the div are replaced.

Comment: I also tried <code>$("#peopleTemplate", document).html()</code> to see if it was the selector context - still no dice within a function.

Comment: I also tried jquery-1.10.2 but the behavior is the same.

Comment: Add some `console.log()` calls so that you can see whether `$('#people-templ')` has a length of 1, and also see what `.html()` returns if the length is 1.

Comment: Thanks, Pointy.  I added the log statement: console.log($("people-templ").length).  It confirmed what I saw in the debugger.  $('#people-temp') returns an array of size 0 from within the callback function.

Comment: Is it possible that some other code is *removing* that script block from the document? JQuery is a global function, and the fact that it's called from inside another function or a callback makes no difference. All that matters is the state of the DOM when the call is made.

Comment: Thanks for making me track that down, Pointy.  I traced to the fact that I used <div id="foo"/> as opposed to <div id="foo"></div>.  What happened is that it treated everything after the <div id='foo'/> as content to be replaced, so all my scripts went buy-buy.

Comment: Great!  I'm happy you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

When using elements for underscore templating, it looks like you need to use the

```
<div id='foo'></div>
```

form instead of just:

```
<div id='foo'/>
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is that in an HTML5 document, the parser *accepts* the `/>` notation, but it **ignores** it!!  In other words, the "self-closing" tag does not actually *work* as a self-closing tag!